# Why dose my OLED Display don't work with ESP32?

Tags: esp32, arduino-ide, lcd

Hello maybe somebody could help me. I try to display Text on my OLED Display with my ESP32. I used [this guide](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp32-ssd1306-oled-display-arduino-ide/). I downloaded every libary and wired it all correct, but still my OLED show this: [Display shows randome pixels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rF7yQ.png). At the bottom of my display ther is this black line. In the guide ther is this first video which shows you an example. At the end of this example there are this stars raining down on de display. The black line showed me that stars to but they go from left to right insted from the top to the bottom. Maybe i have to flip my display 90° but i dont know how to do this with code.

[image]

Comment: Were you able to fix it, I have the exact same issue with my OLED screen using ESP32

Answer (score 0):

You can check the resolution of your diplay.
The following code snippet shows the block where is declared size and executed the command for OLED display

```
#define SCREEN_WIDTH 128 // OLED display width, in pixels
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 64 // OLED display height, in pixels

#define OLED_RESET -1 // Reset pin # (or -1 if sharing Arduino reset pin)
Adafruit_SSD1306 display(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, &Wire, OLED_RESET);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to check your OLED driver and ensure that it's SSD1306. In some cases, I have seen the driver listed as `SH1106` instead of SSD1306, which can lead to issues with the OLED. Therefore, if so, I recommend using a different library such as `U8G2`.

```
U8G2_SH1106_128X64_NONAME_1_HW_I2C u8g2(U8G2_R0, /* reset=*/ U8X8_PIN_NONE);
```

wrong driver

[image]

correct driver
[image]

[Ref](https://luma-oled.readthedocs.io/en/latest/troubleshooting.html)

Comment: Also, you can use the `Adafruit_SH1106` library as well